# Excel populate data based on data selected in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets in excel file. One is 'Test Cases' and other is 'Settings'. In settings sheet, I have 3 columns as below

```
Locator             Locator Type    Field Name
LOGINPAGE_USERID    ID              User Id
LOGINPAGE_PSWD      ID              Password
LOGINPAGE_LOGIN     XPATH           Login
```

In Test Cases sheet, I have columns - 'Locator', 'Locator Type' and 'Field Name'. I have set Data validation on Locator column such that it shows dropdown list whose values are picked from 'Locator'column from 'Settings' sheet.

Now I want Locator Type and Field Name column to be auto populate based on the value I select from the dropdown under 'Locator'column in 'Test Cases' sheet.

Please help.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` is all you need

Comment: Did that answer your question? Please take the time to upvote useful answers and ultimately accept one which best answers your question. (I'm also referring to some of your *other* questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your selected Locator is in `A2`. Locator Type and Field Name, respectively:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Settings!$A$1:$C$4,2,0)
=VLOOKUP($A2,Settings!$A$1:$C$4,3,0)
```

These formulas go on your Test Cases worksheet, as described in the question.

Comment: How do I apply this to the entire column. For example, for 'Locator Type' column, I need this to be applied to the entire column. How do I do this using Data Validation?